# Display missing timestamp given start and end date in python

Tags: python, timestamp, missing-data

Dataset is having time and Temperature values. Start and end date is also given.

```
start_date = '22-02-2018 10:35:29'
end_date = '23-02-2018 10:34:29'

TIMESTAMP           Temp1   Temp2
22-02-2018 14:35    4.34    4.93
22-02-2018 14:36    4.35    5.02
22-02-2018 14:37    4.35    5.1
22-02-2018 14:39    4.31    5.23
22-02-2018 14:40    4.29    5.26
22-02-2018 14:41    4.26    5.24
22-02-2018 14:42    4.24    5.17
22-02-2018 14:47    4.09    4.64
22-02-2018 14:48    4.08    4.55
22-02-2018 14:49    4.08    4.48
22-02-2018 14:50    4.09    4.48
22-02-2018 14:51    4.11    4.5
22-02-2018 14:54    4.22    4.66
22-02-2018 14:55    4.25    4.72
```

Timestamps from the start and end date is missing. So I want to add timestamps from start data and end date corresponding to that NAN values in the temp1 and temp2 data. Frequency is `60S`.

Desired result:

```
TIMESTAMP           Temp1 Temp2
22-02-2018 10:35    NaN NaN
22-02-2018 10:36    NaN NaN
22-02-2018 10:37    NaN NaN
22-02-2018 10:38    NaN NaN
22-02-2018 10:39    NaN NaN
22-02-2018 10:40    NaN NaN
22-02-2018 10:41    NaN NaN
22-02-2018 10:42    NaN NaN
.
.
.
22-02-2018 14:35    4.34    4.93
22-02-2018 14:36    4.35    5.02
22-02-2018 14:37    4.35    5.1
22-02-2018 14:38    NaN     NaN
22-02-2018 14:39    4.31    5.23
22-02-2018 14:40    4.29    5.26
22-02-2018 14:41    4.26    5.24
22-02-2018 14:42    4.24    5.17
22-02-2018 14:43    NaN NaN
22-02-2018 14:44    NaN NaN
22-02-2018 14:45    NaN NaN
22-02-2018 14:46    NaN NaN
22-02-2018 14:47    4.09    4.64
22-02-2018 14:48    4.08    4.55
22-02-2018 14:49    4.08    4.48
```

Comment: Do you need add also dates between, if missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need first `DatetimeIndex` and then [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) - is necessary align values, so was added [`floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) for minute precision:

```
print (df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2018-02-22 14:35:00', '2018-02-22 14:36:00',
               '2018-02-22 14:37:00', '2018-02-22 14:39:00',
               '2018-02-22 14:40:00', '2018-02-22 14:41:00',
               '2018-02-22 14:42:00', '2018-02-22 14:47:00',
               '2018-02-22 14:48:00', '2018-02-22 14:49:00',
               '2018-02-22 14:50:00', '2018-02-22 14:51:00',
               '2018-02-22 14:54:00', '2018-02-22 14:55:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='TIMESTAMP', freq=None)


dates = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='60S').floor('60S')
df = df.reindex(dates)
```

Verifying with changed start and end dates:

```
start_date = '22-02-2018 14:32:29'
end_date = '22-02-2018 14:58:29'

dates = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='60S').floor('60S')
df = df.reindex(dates)
print (df)
                     Temp1  Temp2
2018-02-22 14:32:00    NaN    NaN
2018-02-22 14:33:00    NaN    NaN
2018-02-22 14:34:00    NaN    NaN
2018-02-22 14:35:00   4.34   4.93
2018-02-22 14:36:00   4.35   5.02
2018-02-22 14:37:00   4.35   5.10
2018-02-22 14:38:00    NaN    NaN
2018-02-22 14:39:00   4.31   5.23
2018-02-22 14:40:00   4.29   5.26
2018-02-22 14:41:00   4.26   5.24
2018-02-22 14:42:00   4.24   5.17
2018-02-22 14:43:00    NaN    NaN
2018-02-22 14:44:00    NaN    NaN
2018-02-22 14:45:00    NaN    NaN
2018-02-22 14:46:00    NaN    NaN
2018-02-22 14:47:00   4.09   4.64
2018-02-22 14:48:00   4.08   4.55
2018-02-22 14:49:00   4.08   4.48
2018-02-22 14:50:00   4.09   4.48
2018-02-22 14:51:00   4.11   4.50
2018-02-22 14:52:00    NaN    NaN
2018-02-22 14:53:00    NaN    NaN
2018-02-22 14:54:00   4.22   4.66
2018-02-22 14:55:00   4.25   4.72
2018-02-22 14:56:00    NaN    NaN
2018-02-22 14:57:00    NaN    NaN
2018-02-22 14:58:00    NaN    NaN
```

Another solution, especially if duplicate values is add start and end datetimes and [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with some aggregate function, e.g. `sum`:

```
df.loc[pd.to_datetime(start_date)] = np.nan
df.loc[pd.to_datetime(end_date)] = np.nan
df = df.resample('60S').sum()
```

Comment: Tried this but not getting proper results.

Comment: @N.Mittal - I am confused, why between `22-02-2018 10:42` and `22-02-2018 14:35` are not rows?

Comment: there are rows its just that these are null values . So i forgot to specify those rows. I have edited the question.

Comment: @N.Mittal - OK, but both my solution add `NaN`s values as you need. So why my solution failed for you?

Comment: Your first solution is similar to my solution but its not working out , its giving NaN even for the existing timestamps. I will try the second one .

Comment: @N.Mittal - what is your index? It is `datetimeindex` ?

Comment: new_Data = data.set_index('TIMESTAMP')
using this , datetime is the index

Comment: I think problem with different precision, so second resample solution should working.

Comment: Thanks for the solution . I made changes in the seconds and replced it by 0 . So our first solution is working fine .

Comment: The first solution was working fine but now its not working again.

Comment: @N.Mittal - Data was changed?

Comment: @N.Mittal - What is different in new DataFrame?

Comment: only the timestamp values and corresponding to that temperature values . no change in format as well ..

Comment: @N.Mittal Can you edit question with problematic data?

Comment: @N.Mittal - So if solution work before and now no with same data, then is seems version of pandas is different?

Comment: Pandas version is same and everything is same.

Comment: @N.Mittal - OK, so problem is it working before and not it failed with same data, same pandas? Can you explain more what is problem? Bad output? Some error(s)?

Comment: yes it is not working now, bad output , NaN for all the timestamp.

Comment: @N.Mittal - In my opinion it seems some data problem. are data confidental?

Comment: @N.Mittal - Yes, sure. I have my email in my profile. But not very often check it, so please be patience.

Comment: i guess some problem with data .

Comment: @N.Mittal - If data re not confidental, can you send me csv file to my email?

Comment: okay .. i am actually extracting data from influxdb and then using it